# This piece of code is showing error while working with openCV webcam

Tags: opencv, webcam

I was working with opencv using haarcascade face detection . But this error is creeping and i am not able to get this. So please guide me.

OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

```
import cv2
def videoCam():
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
    while (True):
        ret,frame=cap.read()
        gray_frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        if (ret==False):
            continue
        faces=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_frame,1.3,5)
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.imshow("Video Frame",frame)
        key_pressed=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if(key_pressed==ord('q')):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
videoCam()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting above error because `frame` is `None` in `cv2.cvtColor` function. Please, verify input to the `cv2.VideoCapture` function. It's a device index which is just the number to specify which camera. You haven't mentioned above which camera you are using, i.e., internal or external camera. Read about what device index to use from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html). You can check if the `VideoCapture()` method already initializes your camera object using `print(cap.isOpened())` after `cv2.VideoCapture` function. It will return `True` in case it successfully initialized your camera object.

And, why are doing

```
if (ret==False):
    continue
```

after `cv2.cvtColor`. The main aim of this is to check if the frame is read correctly or not. If the image is read correctly, `ret` will be `True`, else `False`. So, you should check this before using `cv2.cvtColor` function and if it returns `False`, then you should `break` from the loop, instead of using `continue`, otherwise the while loop will keep on running infinitely.